# Android App works in debug but not in release

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing an Android app and I have a problem when I run the app in release mode. If I start the app in **debug** mode I get this type of message in the Logcat (the app doesn't start):

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GoogleApiHandler
>       Process: it.planner, PID: 27326
>       java.lang.SecurityException: In order to use mock mode functionality app it.planner must be selected as the mock location
>   application in developer settings.
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2008)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1954)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeu.zzb(Unknown Source:10)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfa.zzbj(Unknown Source:9)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfd.zzbj(Unknown Source:13)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfk.zzbj(Unknown Source:2)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcee.zza(Unknown Source:4)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzm.zzb(Unknown Source:8)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc.zza(Unknown Source:6)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbo.zzb(Unknown Source:9)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbo.zzaiw(Unknown
>   Source:82)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbo.onConnected(Unknown
>   Source:16)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.onConnected(Unknown
>   Source:2)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zzakr(Unknown Source:130)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzw(Unknown Source:64)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzaks(Unknown Source:51)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown
>   Source:270)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65) E/iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.

Obviously, if I select the **mock** location in **Developer Options**, the app starts and **works fine**.

If I install the **release apk** and I try to start the app, the app **doesn't start** and I get this kind of messagge in Logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: it.planner, PID: 29448
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2054)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2077)
>           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:678)
>           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:632)
>           at it.planner.Home.mainMenu(Home.java:374)
>           at it.planner.Home.computeGeolocation(Home.java:487)
>           at it..planner.Home.access$100(Home.java:80)
>           at it.planner.Home$3$1.onLocationResult(Home.java:344)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcff.zzu(Unknown Source:4)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzci.zzb(Unknown Source:8)
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzcj.handleMessage(Unknown
>   Source:16)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7377)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)

There is no possibility to select the mock location once the app is in release mode, so it doesn't want to start. I've been dealing with this problem for many days. I also tried with **minifyEnabled false** in the Gradle file but it doesn't work.

The gradle file is the following:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] }
        debug {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
```

Comment: the `build.gradle` is irrelevant. what does `Home.java` say at line `374` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is probably because of the Fragment transaction was not committed using the proper API. try to find

```
transaction.commit();
```

and replace it with

```
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Some  more discussion is here: https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/issues/529#issuecomment-224974339